# Bulk-add pronunciations to Anki decks

Tags: discussion, resources

This is what I want to do:

I have a large Anki collection (over 20,000 notes).
I want to add pitch/accent information to each note.

Possible solutions?
I have no idea how to do it, but I know of an Anki addon ([here](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/932119536)) which partially does this, but it is buggy and its source data is not complete at all. I know that there are online resources like [Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E) which display a number corresponding to pitch/accent patterns. But I don't know how to synthesize the various resources in order to get that data into my collection.

In theory, what would I need to be able to bulk-add pronunciation meta-data to a large list of notes?

Comment: This is a question that is relevant to language learning in general. If you don't get any answers, here consider posting it on [Language Learning Stack Exchange](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Done: https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/3474/bulk-add-pronunciations-to-anki-decks